# call method every so often vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I need to call a function every so often, what I want is to update the data every so often for this reason I need to call that method, I'm using vue js.

in the same way I want to know in which property of vue js locate it, thanks, I will investigate all the comments

I need to call the 'listar()' method every 30 seconds

```
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {

            listar(){
            let me=this;
                me.mesas=[];
                axios.get('api/mesas/ListarTodos').then(function(response){
                    //console.log(response);
                    me.mesas=response.data;
                      me.loading=false;
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });



        },
}
</script>
```

This did not work for me

```
setTimeout(() => {
         //
}, 300)
```

**Upgrade 1**

this code actually works for me,but the problem is — it will keep running after you switch to another page, because it’s a single page application.

I'm using clearInterval () but it does not work, the method keeps running even though I change the page (component).
Clear the clear only the first time I enter another page, then no longer

Ref-->https://renatello.com/vue-js-polling-using-setinterval/

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
  export default {

data () {
      return {
        polling: null,

       },
methods: {

        listar(){
                let me=this;
                    me.mesas=[];
                    axios.get('api/mesas/ListarTodos').then(function(response){
                        //console.log(response);
                        me.mesas=response.data;
                          me.loading=false;
                    }).catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });



     pollData () {
      this.polling = setInterval(() => {

         this.listar();
       }, 3000) },

                },


 created () {
      this.pollData()

    },

 beforeDestroy () {
         clearInterval(this.polling)
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `setInterval`

Comment: Update my question, thank you for your comment, now the problem I have is that the method is still running despite changing the page, it is a SPA application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ittus said, you should use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(() => {
    // call listen()
}, 30 * 1000);
```

`setInterval` returns an object you can pass to `clearInterval` in order to stop calling listen.

However, if you want to take into account the time of the request, you could also use `setTimeout` in a .finally block at the end of your (promise) request:

```
axios.get('api/mesas/ListarTodos').then(function(response){
    //console.log(response);
    me.mesas=response.data;
    me.loading=false;
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
}).finally(function(){
    setTimeout(/*call listen in a function*/, 30 * 1000);
});
```

Anyway, it doesn't have much to do with vuejs

Comment: Update my question, thank you for your comment, now the problem I have is that the method is still running despite changing the page, it is a SPA application.